# Slick database configuration

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I have an issue with Slick configuration in my Play application (Play 2.4.3).
I read [documentation article](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick) but want to move dbConfig from controller to specified trait and mixin this trait to repository class.

There are several files in project: ClientRepository (class), BaseClientRepository (trait) and BaseDbRepository (trait).

```
trait BaseDbRepository {
  val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  def withConnection[T](f: => DBIOAction[T, NoStream, Nothing]) = {
    dbConfig.db.run(f)
  }
}

trait BaseClientRepository {
  def getById(id: Int): Future[Client]
  def getByLocation(location: String): Future[Seq[Client]]
}

class ClientRepository extends BaseDbRepository with BaseClientRepository {

  def getById: Future[Client] = withConnection {
    ...
  }

  def getByLocation: Future[Seq[Client]] = withConnection {
    ...
  }
}
```

This works great with my Client controller:

```
class Client extends Controller {
  def getById(id: Int) = ???
}
```

But when I try to use DI with Guice:

```
class Client @Inject()(clientRepository: BaseClientRepository) extends Controller {
  def getById(id: Int) = Action.async {
    // I try to use client repository here
  }
}
```

It failes with the following exception
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: There is no started application
  at com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule.configure(Modules.java:177)

I tried to move this definition `val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)` into Global.scala and it just works, but as I now Global.scala is deprecated now.

So, where is the best place for it?

Update: I use injection module for DI configuration:

```
class InjectionModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() {
    bind(classOf[BaseClientRepository]).toInstance(new ClientRepository)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbConfig should be a lazy val or a function in this case.
That works for me:

```
private lazy val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guice failed to inject an implementation of BaseClientRepository, the annotation  @ImplementedBy can help.

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[ClientRepository])
trait BaseClientRepository {
   def getById(id: Int): Future[Client]
   def getByLocation(location: String): Future[Seq[Client]]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. Exception is the same: There is no started application... P.S. I've updated post with my Guice configuration.